# Windows host file being ignored when using VPN or proxy

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, vpn, proxy

I'm using an app named [Hostblock](https://hostblock.codeplex.com/) to prevent ads and other stuff from being loaded. it works perfect on normal Internet connection but when I use a VPN or http proxy they get ignored and ads load again. I know there are many other solutions to block ads such as browser extensions but I'm using those host entries to block ads in other applications and not just in browsers.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Why is Windows acting like this and programs are easily ignoring my hosts file?
2. What's the workaround for this and how to enforce all applications refer to hosts file even when proxy or VPN is used?

I use a PPTP/L2TP connection which is a file with the extension of .pbk. it's a built-in Windows feature.

I'm using Windows 8.1 X64.

Comment: I am thinking this would defeat the purpose of a vpn, an encrypted tunnel to a remote server.

Comment: Yeah but maybe for third parties, not my own system. but what about for proxies?

Comment: You would have to ask the author(s) of your VPN software what changes it makes to your system when used, I assume this varies from product to product. I have never used proxies so I cannot answer that. It is up to the specific software whether it uses the hosts file or not.

Comment: I don't use a VPN software, I use a PPTP/L2TP connection with the extension of .pbk. it's a built-in Windows feature.

Comment: You never used proxies not even once? that's weird. even fiddler sets up a local proxy.

Comment: I'm a fiddler for sure, just don't use software for that, lol. Never had the need to use a proxy, ok so I'm weird!

Comment: " I use a PPTP/L2TP connection with the extension of .pbk. it's a built-in Windows feature" you might edit your question to include this info.

Comment: Thanx, it's done. cool but proxies are pretty useful for example when you want to access a content in a different country like netflix etc.

Comment: It sounds like your VPN is using a virtual network adapter, so I would guess that the HostBlock software is listening on the physical interface, which has been bypassed.

Comment: That [software](https://hostblock.codeplex.com/) doesn't actually do anything, it is only a text editor like notepad that is only used to edit hosts file. **it relies on Windows' HOSTS file to provide system-wide application-independant address blocking**

Comment: 1. Be away the PPTP isn't quite as secure as other VPN standards, try OpenVPN if you really care about security. 2. I would guess this is because windows anticipates remote workers dialing into a business network with mobile devices(PPTP) and thus receiving DNS down the VPN. In this setup it'd be the desired behavior. I dont know that you'll sort it without third party software in the middle.

Comment: I understand the VPN might use its own server's DNS but why is this happening on http proxies too? Yes PPTP is to weak, I might use SSTP instead which is the most secure protocol on Windows. anyway, nothing is hidden from NSA even if you using 4096-bits RSA encryption ;)